# Suppress the message during copy or rename action for a Worksheet that has a Define Names inside

Tags: excel

Is there any way to eliminate the message we get when we want to create a new Worksheet (Right button on the Worksheet tab, then select: (`Move or Copy...`)

[image: copy a sheet]

and for the Worksheet we want to create a copy has defined some formula inside, so we get the following message:

[image: Message about formula inside]

I don't want to redefine the existing formula names, so I always will take the same action: `Yes`. In my case, the formula `DoneDays` was defined in the Worksheet I wanted to copy.

[image: Name Manager view]

I would like to eliminate this message because I have several formulas/names per sheet, so it is a little annoying to get always such kind of message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found the reason of this problem. After deleting the names that have as value `#REF!` de problem disappears. There is an image in the question for Manager Names view that shows for example that for the name: `DoneDays` with Workbook scope it has this invalid value. After deleting all such names the copy/paste process works fine.